# Couple questions, feedback before a patio install project

Tags: patio

I'm going to be installing a patio behind my house soon and have a couple questions.

Here are sketches of the area, plans, and photos of the area. I'm just outside Boston, so obviously the base is important, given water. https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKcBJ.jpg

My open questions that I haven't resolved (there are a couple additional ones on the plan that I have my own answers to):

1) Do I need subterranean drainage like a french drain along  the south edge of the patio?

2) What about behind the small retaining wall (less than a foot above grade at its highest)?

3) From a aesthetic perspective, should the stone at the landing below the step to the southeast of the photo match the driveway (some kind of concrete paver or cobblestone) or the patio (some kind of bluestone).

4) Finally, am I missing or overlooking anything? There will be a whole other project for the front yard....

Thanks for any help, suggestions, or feedback!